# How to convert fractions into floating points in c++

Tags: c++, class, fractions, friend-function

My requirement is to add,multiply,subtract and divide rational fractions using classes then implement a standalone(nonclass) function `void printRationalAsFloating(const Rational &r)` using `friend` function for printing the passed `Rational` numbers into floating point numbers. My output is fine with `multiplication` but with `addition` is wrong. I don't know if something is wrong with either `friend function` or with `printRationalAsFloating`.

my output:

```
Testing addition : 1/2 * 1/2 = 4/4
Rational as floating:1                //it should be something like 1.00
Testing multiplication : 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4
Rational as floating:0.25
```

int main();

```
cout<<"Testing addition : ";
                    n1 = n2.addition(n3);
                    n2.printRational();
                    cout <<" + ";
                    n3.printRational();
                    cout <<" = ";
                    n1.printRational();
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Rational as floating:";
                    printRationalAsFloating(n1);
                    cout << endl;
                    Rational n1;
                    Rational n2(1,2);
                    Rational n3(n2);
                    cout<<"Testing multiplication : ";
                    n1 = n2.multiplication(n3);
                    n2.printRational();
                    cout <<" * ";
                    n3.printRational();
                    cout <<" = ";
                    n1.printRational();
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Rational as floating:";
                    printRationalAsFloating(n1);
                    cout << "  ";
```

header file:

```
using namespace std;

class Rational {

  public:
    Rational();        // default constructor
    Rational(int, int); //std (initialisation) constructor
    Rational(const Rational&); //copy constructor
    Rational multiplication(const Rational &);
    Rational addition(const Rational &);
    friend void printRationalAsFloating(const Rational &);
    void printRational();
  private:
   int numerator;
   int denominator;
};
```

here is my coding:

```
void printRationalAsFloating(const Rational &r)
{
    float numerator,n;
    float denominator;
    if (r.denominator==0) 
    {
        string exceptionString = "\n\nError: 'Cannot divide by zero'.\n";
        throw exceptionString;
        cout << "ERROR: ATTEMPTING TO DIVIDE BY ZERO" << endl;
        exit(0); // will terminate the program if division by 0 is attempted
    }
    n = r.numerator / r.denominator;

    cout << n ;

}  

using namespace std;
//addition
Rational Rational::addition(const Rational &a)
{ 
      return Rational(numerator * a.denominator + a.numerator * denominator, 
      denominator * a.denominator);
}
//multiplication
Rational Rational::multiplication(const Rational &a)
{ 
   return Rational((numerator * a.numerator) ,denominator * a.denominator);
}

//display fraction
void Rational::printRational()
{
    cout << numerator << "/" << denominator ;
}
```

I tried to make it concise but if you still need further code please comment below and i will upload more for your ease. Thanks

Comment: `n = r.numerator / r.denominator;` This is integer division. You need to cast at least one operand to `double`.

Comment: `cout << "ERROR: ATTEMPTING TO DIVIDE BY ZERO" << endl;` -- This message is too late.  You've already attempted to divide by zero before that message is printed.

Comment: Also, `if (denominator==0)` check should be `r.denominator` and should go before the division.

Comment: Your code has several bugs in it, did you try using a debugger or printing out the values?

Comment: Thanks i have just edited. No i havent use any debugger yet.

Comment: i partly reverted your last edit to show the wrong code again. Please dont fix code in the question after you got answers, because this will make both your question and the answers meaningless to future readers

Comment: BTW, in your post `+` should be used for addition of fractions, not `*`.

Comment: no , i have two separate functions for addition and multiplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void printRationalAsFloating(const Rational &r)
{
float numerator,n,denominator;
if (r.denominator==0) 
    {
        string exceptionString = "\n\nError: 'The denominator of a rational cannot     be zero'.\n";
        throw exceptionString;
        //cout << "ERROR: ATTEMPTING TO DIVIDE BY ZERO" << endl;
        //exit(0); // will terminate the program if division by 0 is attempted
    }
n = (float)r.numerator / r.denominator;

cout << n ;

}
```

Comment: do i still need to write `float` with `r.denominator` ??

Comment: you donot need to write float with both items. One would work and will convert the rest into floats.

Comment: You can do the same thing with double and int as well

Comment: That was the requirement to jjst convert into floats. Thanks alot anyways

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
n = r.numerator / r.denominator;
```

invokes *integer division*.

Try casting at least one operand to `double`, like this:

```
n = r.numerator / (double) r.denominator;
```

Comment: in that case, if i had to add 1/2 + 1/2 other than multiplication the output will be 4/4 as fraction and 1 as floats, why it does not give me something like 1.00 as floats

Comment: Division has higher precedence than addition.  Each term `1/2` will be computed as zero (dividing two `int` values, with rounding toward zero, to give a result of type `int`).    Then the two zeros are added.   If one of the values are converted to `double`, such as `(double)1/2 + 1/2`  then `(double)1/2` is computed as `0.5`  (since that `1` and `2` are both promoted to `double` before division).   `1/2` will still be computed using integer division, giving a result of zero.  That zero will be converted to `double`, in order to add to the value  `0.5`.

Comment: @Peter your explanation doesnt match what OP reports: "will be 4/4 as fraction and 1 as floats" you are explaining why there would be a `0` as float

Comment: @user463035818 - The OP is misinterpreting what results the expression would give.

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing a `int` by and `int`. This gives an `int` later casted to `float`. First convert your `int` to `float`

```
float n = r.numerator / (float)r.denominator;
```

Comment: You don't need to cast both numerator & denominator to `float`, converting just one will work as mentioned by @gsamaras

Comment: in that case, if I Try to do add 1/2 + 1/2 other than multiplication the output will be 4/4 as fraction and 1 as floats, why it does not give me something like 1.00 as floats